# Getting "Uncaught TypeError" when compiling js files with Webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I am trying to create a simple node.js app using Webpack for compiling my javascript files. I am totally new to node.js, so I am having a hard time understanding what I am doing wrong and how it should be done.

I am sorry that it's going to be really long-winded, but I am having trouble with the configuration and I'm not sure which specific file is causing the problem, so I am posting a lot of code. Really sorry.

My app architecture so far is the following:

```
app

 └─app.js
 └─package.json
 └─package-lock.json  
 └─webpack.config.js
 └─views
 |  └─index.ejs
 └─public 
    └─javascript
       └─scripts //where I put functions i am importing into index.js
       |   └─foo.js
       |   └─bar.js
       └─index.js //file with all js functions create
       └─main.js //bundle made by webpacker
```

in my app.js files:

```
 const path = require("path");
 const express = require("express");
 const port = process.env.PORT || "8000";

 const app = express();
 app.set("view engine", "ejs");
 app.use(express.static("public"));
```

in my public/javascript/scripts/foo.js:

```
 const foo = () => {
   ....
 };

 module.exports = { foo };
```

in my public/javascript/index.js:

```
 const foo = require("./scripts/foo");

 foo();
```

in my webpack.config:

```
 const path = require("path");
 module.exports = {
   context: __dirname,
   entry: "./public/javascript/index.js",
   output: {
     path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public/javascript"),
     filename: "main.js"
   },
   watch: true
 };
```

and in my views/index.ejs:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
   <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8" />
     <title>Objects</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />
   </head>
   <body>
     ...
     <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/main.js"></script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Then I start the server with:

```
nodemon ./app.js
```

And start the client with:

```
webpack --config ./webpack.config.js
```

The html loads just fine in the browser, but the javascript doesn't work and the console prints:

```
Uncaught TypeError: r(...) is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.js:1)
    at r (main.js:1)
    at main.js:1
    at main.js:1
```

r(...) is something webpack created in main.js when it compiled all js files, but I don't know what could be wrong there.

Comment: A small detail: your title and tag says "webpacker", which is a Ruby on Rails gem, it seems you meant to use "webpack" instead.

Comment: I'm wondering if it has something to do with the `{ }` brackets around `foo` in your `module.exports`

Comment: Oops. I am too used to RoR, guess I got them mixed haha thanks for the clarification, @Nit.

@c_sagan, the right way to export is without the `{ }` ? I was under the impression they had to be present, I will give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your export:

```js
module.exports = { foo };
```

This is a [shorthand notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) for writing

```js
module.exports = {
    foo: foo,
};
```

That is, an object with a single key `"foo"`, with the value of your function named `foo`.

When you later require the module, you're trying to call your module export, which is not the function, but the object around it. If you want to simply export a single function and import a single function, you can instead do:

```js
module.exports = foo;
```